# Croatian letters enconding + Twitter Bootstrap + Helvetica Neue Pro

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, character-encoding, font-awesome

Twitter bootstrap won't show letter đ ć č ž š,Croatian letters.
I set charset to UTF-8 and it won't do...
I'm getting data form mysql and in database is ok, first i tought it was font Helvetica,so I get Helvetica Neue Pro LT but...not sure i load it correctly...any idea how to load...[Twitter bootstap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) + [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/),

so I tired with Arial, and it won't work!

so any help?
tnx alot

Comment: I hate to ask, but the last I saw an error like that was on an XP box. Any odds you're running such a thing?

Comment: I'm running MAMP on MAC OS X 10.7.5

Comment: what is the charset of the database of your data, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: tried with utf8 / utf8_general_ci / latin2_croatian_ci

Comment: Is  this in all browsers? IE may require some tweaks.

Comment: The collation has nothing to do with the character set - only the sorting and search rules. And unless you have a really good excuse, you should never use other character sets than utf-8.

Answer (score 3):

There can be several reasons.

Before troubleshooting the database, you should first try with some static content to ensure that your editor and server is correctly set up.

Try adding some html content to your php file that contains your croatian characters. If these characters come out wrong in your browser, make sure:

1. Your code editor saves your PHP files using UTF-8 encoding
2. Your webserver outputs your PHP files as UTF-8. To check this, look at the http header in your browser. There should be a line named "Content-Type" with a value of "text/html; charset=UTF-8". Look at this screenshot from Chrome to locate the http header: http://www.jesperkristensen.dk/webstandarder/doctype-chooser/chrome.png

If the static characters come out right, the next step is to troubleshoot the database.

#### The character set

Computers only know numbers by nature, so internally the computer thinks of letters and characters as numbers. For example, the letter `a` is, by default, stored as the number 97 on American computers, while `b` is 98. For a complete list, see http://www.asciitable.com/

Very simplified put, whenever displaying characters on the screen, the computer will use this numeric value and look up the value in a font library to find the appropriate glyph to display on screen.

The set of glyphs (characters) that the computer is searching whenever it is displaying some text is called the character set. The specific encoding rules, that define what numbers map to what glyphs in the character set, are called character encodings.

When people talk about the ASCII set they are talking about a collection of glyphs that include the English alphabet in both uppercase and lowercase, the arabic numbers (0-9) and a handful of special characters. But they may also be referring to the ASCII character encoding which specifies which numbers map to which glyphs. Again - see www.asciitable.com

Unfortunately, there are more than English latin characters and as computers proliferated throughout the world in the 60's and 70's, local character sets, fonts and encodings were invented to suit local needs. These have esoteric names like ISO-8859-5, EUC-JP or IBM860.

Attempting to read a text using a different character encoding standard than the text was encoded with would often cause headaches. English characters would work, because they are represented the same across different encodings and sets, but anything else would break. For instance, the character `æ` is a special Danish vowel character that has numeric value of 230 when using the ISO-8859-1 standard which was the predominant encoding standard in Denmark. However, if you saved a text file containing `In Denmark, an apple is called æble.` to a floppy disk and sent it to a friend in Bulgaria, his computer would assume that the text file is encoded using the ISO-8859-5 standard for cyrillic texts and it would show up as `In Denmark, an apple is called цble` which is wrong, because according to the ISO-8859-5 standard the numeric value of 230 maps to `ц`.

To compare the two character encodings, please see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5

In the olden days, developers had to pick which character set and encoding to use for their application, because no universal solution existed, but fortunately a new character set called Unicode evolved in the 1990's.

This character set includes thousands and thousands of glyphs from around the world, enough to cover pretty much every current alphabet and language in the world. Together with Unicode, a few specifications on how to encode text was devised. The most popular today is called utf-8, which is conveniently backwards compatible with the old American ASCII 7-bit character encoding. Because of that, all valid ASCII text is also valid utf-8 text. This backward compatibility is also a curse, because it frequently leads novice developers to conclude that their software is working, when in fact it is only working with characters present in the ASCII character set.

#### First step - making sure your database is storing text as utf-8

Before you can display the text correctly, it must be stored correctly. Use your SQL management tool to check the character encoding for the table you are working with. If no information is present, defaults are probably inherited from the database schema or server configuration, so check that too.

If your table is NOT using utf-8 or you are unable to verify that it is using utf-8, you may run this command in your SQL tool against your table to explicitly instruct the database to store the data using utf-8:

```
ALTER TABLE name_of_your_table
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf_unicode_ci;
```

This tells the database to store data using utf-8 encoding, making it capable of storing your special characters. Databases also uses a concept called collation which is a set of rules on how glyphs are sorted and compared. For instance ß may be interpreted as two s characters in german, while other languages might consider it a special character that comes before or after normal latin characters when sorting. Unless you have a good reason, use the utf_unicode_ci collation which is language agnostic and will usually sort your things correctly. the `_ci` in the name means case insensitive, meaning that when doing comparisons such as `WHERE country = USA`, records in lowercase will also match.

#### Second step - the webserver and the database needs to speak utf-8 together

Now that your database is storing things the right way, you have to make sure your webserver and database are communicating correctly too. Again, a multitude of environment settings affect their defaults, so it's a good idea to be explicit when connecting to the database. If you are using PDO in PHP to connect, you can use the following example to connect (taken from php.net) :

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
?>
```

What is important here is the options associative array. It contains "SET NAMES utf8" which is a SQL command that is run against the database whenever a connection is opened. It has two implications.

1. It instructs the database that any queries sent subsequently will be encoded using utf-8. That way the database will understand non-ascii characters coming from the webserver.
2. It instructs the database that any responses returned from the database to the web server, will be assumed, by the web server, to be encoded using utf-8 and treated as such.

With a database that stores your data using utf-8 encoding and a web server that connects and transfers query results using utf-8 encoding, you should be ready to display your croatian characters on your website.

Comment: static is ok, it shows all letters i need but,error is in database,for some reason it keeps echo-ing weird symbols,

and how to change font of bootstrap with font-awesome,cause Helvetica Neue doesn't have letters ščćž

Comment: I'm not familiar with either Helvetica Neue or font-awesome, so I don't know what glyphs they contain, so let's stick to Arial for now.

How do you connect to your database?

Comment: mysql_connect($server, $username, $password),mysql_select_db($database)

Comment: I have edited the answer with some background explanation. Also, do not use mysql_connect as it is considered insecure and deprecated, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

If you must, call `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` after connecting, but before querying.

Comment: thanks a lot for explanation,I understand it better now, mysql_set_charset('utf8') helped :) it works like charm :) tnx again :)